# vCenter Server automatic update

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, automatic-updates

Is it possible to update vCenter Server 5.5 (Windows platform) to 5.5u2 with vSphere Update Manager or any other automatic/oneclick way ?

Is there any way other than downloading full iso ?

Comment: Is there a problem with using the full ISO? Is there a reason that the traditional approach won't work for you?

Comment: Yes . Downloading iso . Upload it to remote server which doesn't have internet access . very time waste .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You'd need to download the .ISO package... In this case, you'd need:

```
VMware-VIMSetup-all-5.5.0-2105955-20140901-update02.iso
```

Since you're on the Windows platform, you'd load the .ISO and run the installer on top of your existing installation.

Answer (score 1):

I think over Update Manager you can only update your ESX / ESXi Servers. For Updating vCenter Server you have to download the 3GB iso and install it over this way...

If your vCenter Server is an Windows Server your can unzip the iso File on the Server and start autorun.exe. Here you can use "easy-Install" which contains alle the bundles you need (vCenter Single Sign On, vSphere Web Client, vCenter inventory Service and vCenter Server)

so sorry. I think "oneclick" is not working for vCenter.